# updating current time every second in react without rendering

Tags: reactjs

Many of my components in a react native app require to know what the current time is every second. This way I can show updated real-time information.

I created a simple functionality to set the state with `new Date()`, but whenever I set the state, the component re-renders, which is a waste my case.
Here is what I have:

```
...

export default function App() {
  const [currentDateTime, setCurrentDateTime] = useState(() => new Date().toLocaleString());
  useEffect(() => {
    const secondsTimer = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentDateTime(new Date().toLocaleString());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondsTimer);
  }, [setCurrentDateTime]);
  console.log('RENDERING');
  <Text>{currentDateTime}</Text>
  ...
```

I can see the console logs RENDERING every second.

Is there a way to avoid this rerendering and still update `currentDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, you want to update the DOM without triggering React's lifecycle. This is possible using refs (see [React.useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dateTimeRef = React.useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);

  console.log("RENDERING");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const secondsTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (dateTimeRef.current) {
        dateTimeRef.current.innerText = new Date().toLocaleString()
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondsTimer);
  }, []);

  return <span ref={dateTimeRef} />;
}
```

See working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-snow-kt500?file=/src/App.tsx

---

#### Update 1

If you want to use a component such as `Text`, then the component will have to forward the ref to the dom, like here:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Text = React.forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement>((props: any, ref) => {
  console.log("RENDERING TEXT")
  return <span ref={ref}></span>
});

export default function App() {
  const dateTimeRef = React.useRef<HTMLSpanElement>(null);

  console.log("RENDERING APP");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const secondsTimer = setInterval(() => {
      if (dateTimeRef.current) {
        dateTimeRef.current.innerText = new Date().toLocaleString();
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondsTimer);
  }, []);

  return <Text ref={dateTimeRef} />;
}
```

See working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-moon-9zsh2?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This is promising. But how do I update the text of a react native <Text> element with ref.current?

Comment: Since I have no way of knowing what `Text` looks like, I can't really answer that. Although, you can use `React.forwardRef` to reference the DOM inside the `<Text />`.

Comment: That's great, but how do you write an equivalent version for React Native? I tried to use it but getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method; It's purpose is for preventing unnecessary renders. Add this method and tell your component not to update if this particular part of your state changes. As an example, you might add this shouldComponentUpdate() that rejects updates that are more than

```
// Example logic for only re-rendering every 5 seconds; Adapt as needed.
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.lastUpdatedTimeInSeconds+5 >= nextState.timeinseconds) {
    return false;
  }
  this.lastUpdatedTimeInSeconds = nextState.timeinseconds
  return true;
}
```

Further Reading: https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html

Answer (score 0):

Eliya Cohen's answer was conceptually correct. To avoid re-rendering, we cannot use state with an interval. We need to reference the element. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to adopt Eliya's React code to React Native in the same manner, so I did some more digging and found docs on [directly manipulating React Native components](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation).
In short, you can manipulate built in RN components' PROPS and avoid re-rendering by not changing the state.
Since the `<Text>` component doesn't set its value with a prop, such as `<Text text="my text" />`, we are not able to use this method to update it. But what does work is updating the value of a `TextInput` since its set with the `value` prop. All we need to do to make the `<TextInput>` behave like a `<Text>` is to set its prop `editable` to false, and of course avoid default styling of it that would make it look like an input.

Here is my solution. If someone has a better one, please do propose it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Timer: React.FC = () => {
  updateTime = (currentTime) => {
    time.setNativeProps({ text: currentTime });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const secondsTimer = setInterval(() => {
      updateTime(new Date().toLocaleString());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(secondsTimer);
  }, []);

  return <TextInput ref={(component) => (time = component)} editable={false} />;
};

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this and this is what that worked for me after a few attempts with Typescript.

```
    const timeTextInput = useRef<TextInput>(null);

useEffect(()=>{
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        timeTextInput.current?.setNativeProps({ text: new Date().toLocaleString() });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
}, []);
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.